# Bootstrap Grid System on mobiles?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

See the following [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gkbc96he/)

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div style="background: blue;">
      test &amp; test &amp;
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div style="background: yellow;">
      test &amp; test &amp;
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div style="background: red;">
      test &amp; test &amp;
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div style="background: green;">
      test &amp; test &amp;
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

When you shrink the browser, isn't it supposed to add a margin (top & bottom) when you shrink the window?

Am I missing something or does this have to be added in media queries?

Comment: looks like you have missed container. you need to enclose your row div inside container like this `<div class="container"> .... </div>`

Comment: The question wasn't about the page margins, but the margin between columns when they drop down on each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns do not have a margin by default on Bootstrap grid system. Rows however do, but in order to add some margin to the bottom you will have to do by adding some simple CSS:

```
.row > .col-md-3 {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Or if you don't want this to be a common rule, just add some custom class or id to specify this a bit more.

You can easily see the CSS rules being used on the columns by using your browser's **inspector tool**. Columns do not have margin, but padding (left and right, not vertically). You can insert the common CSS rule above to a Media Query if you feel it is better that way, kind of depends on your project.

Applying it on Media Query:

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
{
   .row > .col-md-3 {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
}
```

Which ever suites you the best.

Comment: He wants to add margin on mobile view, col-md is not targeting mobile.